# Workflow of role/permission based content filtering using Entrust Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and added Entrust for roles and permissions.

I don't know how to use the permissions. If I have a permission `create-post` means what will it do?

create option in the Post controller will be permit? Or we need to assign a permission name to the page?

Please suggest an example. Even I don't know where to check permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow of Entrust is as follows

**Create roles**

```
Role::create(['name' => $role]);
```

e.g admin, reader etc

**Create permissions**

```
Permission::create($permission);
```

e.g can_read_post, can_edit_post, can_delete_post

**Assign permissions to roles**

```
$role = Role::where('admin)->first();
$role->perms()->sync($ids); //here the ids are ids of permissons which you want to assign
```

e.g admin has permissions (can_read_post, ca_edit_post, can_delete_post) and reader has permissions (ca_read_post)

**Assign roles to users**

You can assign a role to many users.

```
    $user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

**Filter content based on Role or Permission**

The basic setup has been completed. Now you can filter the content of your website using different methods. Here I will discuss a few

**Define a filter in filters.php and apply on route**

filters.php

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if(!Entrust::hasRole('Administrator'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

routes.php

```
    Route::group(['before' => ['admin']], function(){
      //add some routes which will require admin role
      //any user which has not admin role will be redirected to home page
    }
```

**In your views**

```
@if(Entrust::can('can_edit_post'))
//add some html which will only be visible to users who has such a role which has this permission
@endif
```

**In your controllers/models/repos**

Similarly you can filter content in models/controllers/repos etc.

So I guess you have got the basic idea. Now you can use Entrust functions almost anywhere. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly what we need to done to implement **Entrust Laravel Package** for role based permission is as below.

**Install the package** as per per the instructions given in 
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

After all, done with the above Package(GitHub) like database table creation, Middleware, Controllers and all.

When a user login in the system, then there is an array provided by Auth, that contains all the actions user can (actions ability logged in user can) take.

Let a suppose we have a Controller named as CategoryController as below.

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
    {                
        $this->middleware('permission:category_index', ['only' => ['index']]); 
        $this->middleware('permission:category_create', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:category_edit', ['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:category_delete', ['only' => ['delete']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:category_view', ['only' => ['show']]);     
    }
}
```

We generally have 5 actions in a Controller, If we have a single route (called as resource route) in our routers/web.php file for all CRUD actions of single controller.

In this example, suppose we have all these 5 methods. So we also have entry in permission for these in permission table.. like I have

**Permission Table**

```
id  display_name    name
5   Delete Category category_delete
4   Edit Category   category_edit
3   Create Category category_create
2   List Category   category_index
```

We just need to add these permission names in our controllers as I have done in the CategoryController, If you use hyphon in permission table's name filed, then use like

```
$this->middleware('permission:category-create', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
```

Write all permissions in the controller constructor.

that' it!!

It will automatically check the logged-in user ability and according to the database entry in permission_role (relation table of role and permission), It will either show the page or access denied for that user.

Hope this works !!